# Resolve overfitting in a convolutional network

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-classification, overfitting-underfitting

I've written a snippet to classify Omniglot images. I calculate the training and validation losses in each epoch, where the latter is computed using images that were not seen by the network before. The two plots are as below:

[image: Training loss]
[image: Validation loss]

Since the training loss decreases while the validation loss increases, I have concluded that my model overfits. I've tried several suggestions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122380/neural-network-immediately-overfitting)) to overcome this, including:

- Increasing the size of the training set.
- shuffling the data.
- Adding dropout layers (up to p=0.9).
- Using smaller model.
- Altering the architecture.
- Changing the learning rate.
- Reducing the batch size.
- Adding weight decay.

However, the validation loss still increases. I wonder if there are any other suggestions to improve this behavior or if this is not overfitting, but the problem is something else. Below is the snippet used in this question.

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

from torch import nn, optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        dim_out = 964

        # -- embedding params
        self.cn1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 7)
        self.cn2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 4)
        self.cn3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)

        # -- prediction params
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(256, 170)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(170, 50)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(50, dim_out)

        # -- non-linearity
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.Beta = 10
        self.sopl = nn.Softplus(beta=self.Beta)

    def forward(self, x):

        y1 = self.pool(self.bn1(self.relu(self.cn1(x))))
        y2 = self.pool(self.bn2(self.relu(self.cn2(y1))))
        y3 = self.relu(self.bn3(self.cn3(y2)))


        y3 = y3.view(y3.size(0), -1)

        y5 = self.sopl(self.fc1(y3))
        y6 = self.sopl(self.fc2(y5))

        return self.fc3(y6)


class Train:
    def __init__(self):

        self.device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

        # -- data
        dim = 28
        batch_size = 400
        my_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((dim, dim)), transforms.ToTensor()])
        trainset = torchvision.datasets.Omniglot(root="./data/omniglot_train/", download=False, transform=my_transforms)
        validset = torchvision.datasets.Omniglot(root="./data/omniglot_train/", background=False, download=False,
                                                     transform=my_transforms)
        self.TrainDataset = DataLoader(dataset=trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
        self.ValidDataset = DataLoader(dataset=validset, batch_size=len(validset), shuffle=False)
        self.N_train = len(trainset)
        self.N_valid = len(validset)

        # -- model
        self.model = MyModel().to(self.device)

        # -- train
        self.epochs = 3000
        self.loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

    def train_epoch(self):

        self.model.train()
        train_loss = 0
        for batch_idx, data_batch in enumerate(self.TrainDataset):
            # -- predict
            predict = self.model(data_batch[0].to(self.device))

            # -- loss
            loss = self.loss(predict, data_batch[1].to(self.device))

            # -- optimize
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()
            train_loss += loss.item()

        return train_loss/(batch_idx+1)

    def valid_epoch(self):

        with torch.no_grad():
            self.model.eval()
            for data_batch in self.ValidDataset:
                # -- predict
                predict = self.model(data_batch[0].to(self.device))

                # -- loss
                loss = self.loss(predict, data_batch[1].to(self.device))

        return loss.item()

    def __call__(self):

        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            train_loss = self.train_epoch()
            valid_loss = self.valid_epoch()

            print('Epoch {}: Training loss = {:.5f}, Validation loss = {:.5f}.'.format(epoch, train_loss, valid_loss))

        torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), './model_stat.pth')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_train = Train()
    my_train()
```

Comment: Overfitting is always a tricky problem to solve. I don't see anything specific in your provided code snippet that would definitely cause over-fitting. A couple of things to check; you have three fairly large fully connected layers, and due to the large number of parameters, fully connected layers are often-times the cause of overfitting. Also, in this snippet you aren't actually reporting the loss on the val set, just the loss from the last validation batch.

Comment: Also, you have the flag background=False in for your validation set, and not for your training set. I'm not sure exactly what that means, but if it makes your validation set very different from your training set, that could cause over-fitting issues. Your model might be learning more from the background in the train set, and with the background not present in the validation set it is completely lost.

Comment: @JackRickman Thanks for the comments. Re comment #1: I use `batch_size=len(validset)` for the validation set, so I only have a single batch. Re comment #2: In omniglot dataset, the training set is called background and test set is called evaluation. So `background=True` means that it is training data and `background=False` means it is test data. See Omniglot documentation: https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.Omniglot.html

Answer (score 0):

If your train accuracy is good but testing (data not used in training) accuracy is bad then you have an overfitting problem. I had the same problem with a CNN model. You can use two methods to overcome overfitting. First is early stopping for your train and second is regularization. Check the below example:

```
# L2 regularizers for layers
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(32, 32)),
    keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(32, 32, 1)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=tf.nn.relu,  use_bias=True , kernel_regularizer =tf.keras.regularizers.l2( l=0.01)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax', use_bias=True)
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
#Early Stopping
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
                            validation_data=(X_dev, Y_dev), 
                            epochs=4000, 
                            callbacks=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss'))
```

Do not forget to import for early stopping.

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```